# Finding median with pandas transform

Tags: python, pandas

I needed to find the median for a pandas dataframe and used a piece of code from this previous SO answer: [How I do find median using pandas on a dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063259/how-i-do-find-median-using-pandas-on-a-dataset).

I used the following code from that answer:

```
 data['metric_median'] = data.groupby('Segment')['Metric'].transform('median')
```

It seemed to work well, so I'm happy about that, but I had a question: how is it that transform method took the argument 'median' without any prior specification? I've been reading the documentation for transform but didn't find any mention of using it to find a median.

Basically, the fact that .transform('median') worked seems like magic to me, and while I have no problem with magic and fancy myself a young Tony Wonder, I'm curious about how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend diving into the source code to see exactly why this works (and I'm mobile so I'll be terse).

When you pass the argument `'median'` to `tranform` pandas converts this behind the scenes via `getattr` to the appropriate method then behaves like you passed it a function.

Comment: Good call. I'll look into the source here. Thanks so much, tshauck!