# Calculate medians of data-frame column based on referencing 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

`a = [['A',1,2,3], ['A',0,4,5], ['A',0,6,7],['A',4,6,2],['B',7,3,7],['B',1,6,8],['B',6,2,6],['B',2,5,1],['C',4,2,3],['C',3,9,2],['C',2,7,1],['C',2,3,7]]`

`df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['name','one', 'two', 'three'])`

that looks like:

```
   name  one  two  three
0     A    1    2      3
1     A    0    4      5
2     A    0    6      7
3     A    4    6      2
4     B    7    3      7
5     B    1    6      8
6     B    6    2      6
7     B    2    5      1
8     C    4    2      3
9     C    3    9      2
10    C    2    7      1
11    C    2    3      7
```

How can I create a new column that is the medians of column `three` where the `name` values are the same?  So my desired output would look like:

```
   name  one  two  three  median
0     A    1    2      3     4.0
1     A    0    4      5     4.0
2     A    0    6      7     4.0
3     A    4    6      2     4.0
4     B    7    3      7     6.5
5     B    1    6      8     6.5
6     B    6    2      6     6.5
7     B    2    5      1     6.5
8     C    4    2      3     2.5
9     C    3    9      2     2.5
10    C    2    7      1     2.5
11    C    2    3      7     2.5
```

so for example where `name` = `A` the median of 3,5,7 and 2 is calculated to equal 4.0 and entered into the median column where name is equal to `A`.

Comment: in particular the last line of code of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066674/9274732)

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `groupby().transform`:

```
df['median'] = df.groupby('name')['three'].transform('median')
```

Output:

```
   name  one  two  three  median
0     A    1    2      3     4.0
1     A    0    4      5     4.0
2     A    0    6      7     4.0
3     A    4    6      2     4.0
4     B    7    3      7     6.5
5     B    1    6      8     6.5
6     B    6    2      6     6.5
7     B    2    5      1     6.5
8     C    4    2      3     2.5
9     C    3    9      2     2.5
10    C    2    7      1     2.5
11    C    2    3      7     2.5
```